# Form a new array with mismatched elements of two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in PHP and now i'm facing a problem with arrays.
I have two sets of arrays.I want to form a result array which contains all the mismatched elements in both the array.

eg:

```
array1=Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 ) 

array2=Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2]=>9)
```

result array what i'm expecting should be

result `array=Array([0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 9 )`

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: no array_diff() returns array like this Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 ) i want to form an array by excluding the common elements

Comment: what i have tried is given below
$array1=Array ( 1, 2 ,3 , 4 , 5 ) ;

$array2=Array ( 1,9);

$resultarray=array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($resultarray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = [1,2,9];

$diff1 = array_diff($array1, $array2); //Find difference element in 1st array
$diff2 = array_diff($array2, $array1); //Find difference element in 2nd array

print_r(array_merge($diff1, $diff2)); // Merge the results
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 9
)
```

In one line:

```
print_r(array_merge(array_diff($array1,$array2),array_diff($array2,$array1));
```

---

**Update 1 :** From the comments

It is because, your array values has *spaces*. Just trim out:

Use

```
$array1 = array_map("trim", $prev_array); 
$array2 = array_map("trim", $checked_array);
```

Instead of:

```
$array1 = $prev_array; 
$array2 = $checked_array;
```

Comment: but in my code its showing like array1: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )  array2: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )  and result array:Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 2 ).i dont knw why this happens

Comment: $checked_array=explode(',',$checkedids);
  $prev_array=explode(',',$previds);  $array1 = $prev_array;
$array2 = $checked_array;

$diff1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$diff2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
$result_array=array_merge($diff1, $diff2);
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2 );
print_r($result_array);

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="checkedValues" id="checkedValues" value="1,2">                                                                                                         <input type="hidden" name="prevtardy" id="prevtardy" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"> this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Get elements from both arrays that are not present in the other. Then merges the results.

```
array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1))
```